# How can I run a windows forms apps on Mac?

Tags: c#, macos

I'm trying to run a windows forms app on Mac but it shows this error:

```
WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all
```

I've also tried to install mono with Homebrew. When I run `mono myProgram.exe` it shows the same error.

`mono32 myProgram.exe` displays `Bad CPU type in executable: mono32` and `mono --arch=32 myProgram.exe` doesn't work either.

I'm using OSX 10.15.2

Comment: Windows Forms on Mac is gone for good. Please use a more actively maintained framework to build your application there, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is for a school project and one of the requisites is to use this :(

Comment: Then time to ask your teacher/school to adapt to the changes. They can no longer live in the past, and even in the past WinForms on Mac was not a smart choice.

Comment: Chances are in the field OP wont always be working on the most up-to-date cutting edge software either.

Comment: Finally I think I´ll opt for a windows virtual machine, thanks everyone!